# findout js code traverse to which element in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

for dom manipulation we write code as below.
for dom manipulating first we must traverse to the DOM element. 
iwant to know how to figure it out our written code is traverse to which element in DOM.

as example code below

```
$(document).on('click', '.block_docmanage', function (event)
{           
  cl1ele = $(this).closest('.panel.panel-default.level1').find('.panel-headinglevel1 > h4 > .docmgCategoryBlock');
}):
```

Comment: Check my answer. It should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the XPath of the element in the DOM through the following. It would alert something like `/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/h4/div[3]...` (actual path of the element in the DOM)

```
function getXPath( element ) {
    var val = element.value;
    var xpath = '';
    for ( ; element && element.nodeType == 1; element = element.parentNode ) {
        var id = $(element.parentNode).children(element.tagName).index(element) + 1;
        id > 1 ? (id = '[' + id + ']') : (id = '');
        xpath = '/' + element.tagName.toLowerCase() + id + xpath;
    }
    return xpath;
}   

$(document).on('click', '.block_docmanage', function (event) {           
    cl1ele = $(this).closest('.panel.panel-default.level1').find('.panel-headinglevel1 > h4 > .docmgCategoryBlock');
    var element_hierarchy = getXPath(cl1ele.get[0]);
    alert(element_hierarchy);
}):
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do an alert with the element's id on clicking?

```
     $(document).on('click', '.block_docmanage', function (event){
       cl1ele = $(this).closest('.panel.panel-default.level1').find('.panel-headinglevel1 > h4 > .docmgCategoryBlock').attr("id");
       alert(cl1ele)
}):
```

Comment: if there is no id(cant put a id because html is generating by php loop)and class are duplicate what will do next.... ?

Comment: but you can add an ids in the php loop. Or you can alert the html content adding .html() instead of .attr("id").

Comment: ok is there any way without  alerting id,content to do this.i mean visually we can see the element.

Comment: instead of .attr("id") add .css("border", "4px solid red") and the element will be bordered in red. and remove the alert.